# How to check the visibility of a datatable row?

Tags: javascript, html, datatable, filtering, webix

Is it possible to check the visibility of the particular datatable row?

I found only `isColumnVisible` and `getVisibleCount`, but both of them are irrelevant and as far as I can see, there's no such solution for the rows.

How can I do such thing? For instance, after the filtering I can get **all** data items, but that's all. It's the only idea I've come up with:

```
   onAfterFilter:function(){
      var dataId = this.data.pull;
      var keys = Object.keys(dataId);          
      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
        console.log(this)
      }            
    }
```

http://webix.com/snippet/c6ecdcd5

Answer (score 1):

Ok it feels like a long way of doing this. And I've not done anything other than just get it to work.

But you will find all of the ids you need in `this.data.order` so the following code puts all the filtered items into `filteredObjs`

```
var dataId = this.data.pull;
var keys = Object.keys(dataId);
var filteredIds = this.data.order;
var filteredObjs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < filteredIds.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        if (filteredIds[i] === dataId[keys[j]].id) {
            filteredObjs.push(dataId[keys[j]]); 
        }
    }
}
console.log(filteredObjs);
```

Not saying its perfect. But its a start...

Comment: A great start and works just as needed, thank you! I've also thought about the existence of nodes in DOM, but it also seems a quite uncommon approach. Not sure if I will succeed. Thanks again.

Comment: Eventually, I found that there's `getItemNode`(I've thought I need to use `getNode` of the entire datatable, but this method is useless here). The point is that the nodes of the invisible items are `undefined`, so I suppose it gives me a precise info about the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you need to change `console.log(this)` to `console.log(keys[i])`

Comment: Agree, I've fixed the sample.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the [data-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40557676/5542606) made by @ShaunParsons I found that it's possible to check the visibility through the `getItemNode` function, as the nodes of the invisible items are `undefined`.

http://webix.com/snippet/4f31a5b5

```
    onAfterFilter:function(){
      var dataId = this.data.pull;
      var keys = Object.keys(dataId);                   

      for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.getItemNode(keys[j]))            
      }            

    }
```